How to check that 2 AVAudioNodes attached to the same AVAudioEngine are synchronized
Context:
I have 2 AVAudioNode instances (I call them Node 1 and Node 2) -- attached to the same AVAudioEngine.
Both nodes have the same output format with identical settings: it's AVLinearPCM format.
These 2 nodes go into the same AVAudioMixerNode, so I'd like to check that they start outputting sound in sync.
Question:
How can one check with good precision (say < 1 ms) that Node 1's first frame corresponding to a nonzero sound and Node 2's first frame corresponding to a nonzero sound are output at the same time?
Current solution:
I use installTap() at each node output and then log the time at which the system captures output buffers. But since buffers are output only every 0.1 s and I want more precision, I also log the first non-zero index of the raw PCM-format array (assuming higher index means later time). I'm not sure this strategy gives me reliable accuracy beyond 0.1 s.
node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)) { buffer, when in
    if let channelData = buffer.floatChannelData {
            let frameCount = Int(buffer.frameLength)
            let audioData = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: channelData[0], count: frameCount))
            if let index = audioData.firstIndex(where: { $0 != 0 }) {
                print("Output Time: \(when)")
                print("The first nonzero value is at index: \(index).")
            }
    }
}

